# Is it possible to profile a compiled Java program?

Tags: java, profiling

I have a compiled Java program I'd like to profile.

I also have the source. But I don't control the compilation step. So I can't add flags to the compiler.

Are there any tools that I can point at the compiled application and still get an idea which bits are taking the time, consuming the memory etc?

Comment: Is it being compiled with or without debug symbols? Technically, you're always profiling compiled code.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to profile your application by monitoring it's process at runtime? At compile time, you can't be sure exactly how things are going to execute (like an application that executes based on user input. you can only predict what the input will be). It seems more logical to run the application, then let a monitoring tool pick up on the details you are wondering

Comment: Yes @VinceEmigh. That's what I mean.

Comment: Yes it's possible. There are many tools online, such as JProfiler, that allow you to monitor a JVM process from a third party program. Or you could use VisualVM, which comes bundled with the JDK

Comment: Also thought I should mention that this question doesn't seem to be on topic, since it's basically asking for tool recommendations :s But then again, you could just be wondering if it's actually possible or not, without wondering how... In all, questions like this can easily be answered by googling

Comment: Can you run it under a debugger? with symbols?

Comment: Can I do that without setting compiler flags?